# Javascript use count variable in a for

Tags: javascript

Instead of writing this

```
req.session.personne_1_nom = req.body.personne_1_nom;
req.session.personne_2_nom = req.body.personne_2_nom;
req.session.personne_3_nom = req.body.personne_3_nom;
req.session.personne_4_nom = req.body.personne_4_nom;
```

I would like to use iteration to have less lines to write ;)

Something like :

```
for (let toto = 1; toto < 5; toto++) {
        req.session.personne_+toto+_nom = req.body.personne_+toto+_nom;
    }
```

How to add the toto variable in this line ?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Address the object property by name:

```
for (let toto = 1; toto < 5; toto++) {
        req.session["personne_"+toto+"_nom"] = req.body["personne_"+toto+"_nom"];
    }
```